# Why do I need a separate handler from checked input?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Unable to get the value of the checked input (true or false).

```
function Login() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({
    ...values,
    [name]: value
    }));
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log({inputs});
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="email" name="mail" value={inputs.mail || ""} onChange={handleChange}/>
      <input type="password" name="pass" value={inputs.pass || ""} onChange={handleChange}/>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value={inputs.check || false} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label>Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
export default LoginGoogle
```

Tried

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  const check = event.target.checked;
  setInputs(values => ({
    ...values,
    [name]: value || check
  }));
};
```

For

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value={inputs.checked} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

And

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" checked={inputs.checked} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

It works, but I am certain I am going about it wrong. Tutorials seem to concentrate on input objects of similar key-values, e.g. multiple checkboxes, multiple text input, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that checkbox values never change, only their `checked` property does.

Ideally, you'd use a different change handler

```jsx
const onCheckboxChange = ({ target: { name, checked } }) => {
  setInputs((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [name]: checked,
  }));
};

return (
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="check"
    checked={inputs.check}
    onChange={onCheckboxChange}
  />
);
```